# How do I make jcaptcha work with Spring Session?

Tags: servlets, captcha, spring-session, jcaptcha

We implemented Spring Session backed by Redis and have a cluster of Tomcat servers. When we turned sticky sessions off by not setting the jvmRoute we keep getting "Text verification failed" in the jcaptcha service. I assume this is because the jcaptcha servlet knows nothing about the Spring Dispatcher servlet, which has all of the Spring Session filters, and thus cannot read the session variable. How can we make jcaptcha work with Spring Session?

Here is our setup:

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jcaptcha</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.octo.captcha.module.servlet.image.SimpleImageCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jcaptcha</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jcaptcha/jcaptcha.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**CustomHttpSessionAppInitializer.java**

```
public class CustomHttpSessionAppInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {}
```

**RedisSessionConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisSessionConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisServerName;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer redisServerPort;

    @Value("${spring.redis.database}")
    private Integer redisServerDatabase;

    @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
    private String redisServerPassword;

    @Value("${spring.server.affinity}")
    private Boolean isServerAffinity = Boolean.FALSE;

    @Autowired
    private SessionIdentifierService sessionIdentifierService;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisServerName, redisServerPort);
        config.setDatabase(redisServerDatabase);
        config.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisServerPassword));
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
    }

    /*
     * We need to register every HttpSessionListener as a bean to translate SessionDestroyedEvent and SessionCreatedEvent into
     * HttpSessionEvent. Otherwise we will got a lot of warning messages about being Unable to publish Events for the session.
     * See Spring Session Docs at:
     * {@link} https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-httpsessionlistener
     */
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
        serializer.setUseBase64Encoding(false);
        if (isServerAffinity) {
            serializer.setJvmRoute(sessionIdentifierService.getJvmRoute());
        }
        return serializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem integrating jcaptcha with Spring Session. As long as there is a way of loading the session from Redis (via a SESSION cookie in this case) and the session exists, calling `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(false)` will return the Redis-backed session.

This works in any filter and servlet that is called **AFTER** the springSessionRepositoryFilter. If you look at the source code of `SessionRepositoryFilter`, you will see that the `HttpServletRequest` is swapped with a `SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper`.

So your `SimpleImageCaptchaServlet` and whichever servlet you use to validate the user response will obtain a SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper that will seemlessly give you access to the Redis-backed session.

The problem then might be your configuration; the springSessionRepositoryFilter might not be registered with the container, especially since you’re using both web.xml and a Servlet 3.0+ `WebApplicationInitializer`. If your app works properly, then your web.xml is most likely working fine. Are you using a `WebApplicationInitializer` to load your web.xml? If not, then it might be that your Java Config is not loading.  Make sure your web.xml loads your configuration somehow, perhaps by enabling component scanning (`<context:component-scan/>`) in the contextLoaderListener xml config file to load your Java Config along with:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
```

to load the configuration that will create the filter, which you must then add to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Check out the [Spring Session reference on XML config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/)